# Google + login and save .csv file in google drive in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to use google+ login in iOS app and also save `.csv` file in google drive.

I implemented google+ sign in from link

:https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

its working great,

for Google drive implementation I Used link:

https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart
it working well.

But when I implemented both in single project it give flowing

*******errror:*******

> uplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTLBatchQuery.queries* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTLBatchQuery.additionalHTTPHeaders* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>       twrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPFetchHistory.cookieStorage* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMCookieStorage in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMCookieStorage in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMCachedURLResponse in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMCachedURLResponse in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMURLCache in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMURLCache in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMHTTPFetchHistory in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMHTTPFetchHistory in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPFetchHistory.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.uploadFileHandleLength* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.statusCode* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.isRestartedUpload*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.chunkFetcher* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.locationURL* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.locationChangeBlock* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.uploadData* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.uploadFileHandle*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.uploadMIMEType* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.responseHeaders*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.delegateFinishedSEL* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.needsManualProgress* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.initialBodyLength*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.initialBodySent*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.currentOffset* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.delegateSentDataSEL* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.isPaused* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.chunkSize* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMHTTPUploadFetcher in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMHTTPUploadFetcher in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2AuthorizationArgs.request* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2AuthorizationArgs.delegate* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2AuthorizationArgs.completionHandler* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2AuthorizationArgs.thread* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2AuthorizationArgs.error* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2AuthorizationArgs.sel* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.authorizationQueue* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.parameters* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.clientID* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.clientSecret*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.redirectURI* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.authorizationTokenKey* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.tokenURL* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.expirationDate*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.additionalTokenRequestParameters* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.additionalGrantTypeRequestParameters*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.refreshFetcher*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.userData* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.properties* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.fetcherService*
>   in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.parserClass* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2Authentication.shouldAuthorizeAllRequests* in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2ServiceProviderGoogle in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2ErrorDomain in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2ErrorMessageKey in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2ErrorRequestKey in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2ErrorJSONKey in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2FetchStarted in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2FetchStopped in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2FetcherKey in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeKey in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeToken in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeRefresh in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeAssertion in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeUserInfo in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2ErrorObjectKey in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2UserSignedIn in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2AccessTokenRefreshed in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2RefreshTokenChanged in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2AccessTokenRefreshFailed in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>   duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2WebViewStartedLoading in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>
> ```
> /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain in:
>       /Users/chandankumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Daily_Expense_Manager-evhftwrkvohkdralzxbvrskbxwny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
>       /Users/chandankumar/Desktop/DEM/Google+/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
>   ld: 363 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is late, but i faced the same issue just 2 mins ago, i removed `libGTLTouchStaticLib.a` from `Link Binary with Libraries` section, and it compiled successfully.